# Custom gulp-jshint reporter not working with gulp-shell

Tags: gulp

The following reporter doesn't seem to work with `gulp-shell`.

```
...
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
...
var mReporter = {
    reporter: function (errors) {
        shell.task([
              'echo "echo hello"'
            ]);
        console.log("console.log hello");
    }
};
...
```

`console.log hello` is being displayed but `echo hello` is not?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

```
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
...
gulp.task('mTask', shell.task([
    'echo "echo hello"'
]));
...
var mReporter = {
    reporter: function (errors) {
        gulp.start('mTask');
        console.log("console.log hello");
    }
};
...
```